# Thread safe algorithm for arrays information manipulation

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I have a program which requires a usage of threads and it must be thread safe. I do not have much experience with threads and critical sections, but as much as I know you must lock code sections where resources are being read and written to. Program is working, but I do not know if I did it correctly.

`DataB` code was added to answer users Incomputable question. It is just a class which stores information required for program to work.

```
class DataB {
public:
    DataB() { }
    DataB(double sF, int sC, string n);
    double getField(void);
    void increaseFieldCount(void);
    void decreaseFieldCount(void);
    int getFieldCount(void);
    void setField(double f);
    void setCountField(int fC);
    string getName(void);
private:
    string name;
    double field;
    int fieldCount;
};

    DataB::DataB(double sF, int sC, string n) {
    field = sF;
    fieldCount = sC;
    name = n;
}

double DataB::getField(void) {
    return field;
}

void DataB::increaseFieldCount() {
    fieldCount++;
}

int DataB::getFieldCount(void) {
    return fieldCount;
}

void DataB::decreaseFieldCount(void) {
    fieldCount--;
}

void DataB::setCountField(int cF) {
    fieldCount = cF;
}

void DataB::setField(double f) {
    field = f;
}

string DataB::getName(void) {
    return name;
}

mutex threadLock;

void threadRemove(int dataStart, int dataEnd, int dataCount, DataB B[],  DataB V[], int &sortedCount) {
    bool changed = true;

    while (changed || sortedCount != dataCount ) {
        changed = false;

        for (int i = dataStart; i < dataEnd; i++) {

            threadLock.lock();

            int count = V[i].getFieldCount();

            threadLock.unlock();

            if (count > 0) {

                threadLock.lock();

                double delItem = V[i].getField();

                threadLock.unlock();

                for (int x = 0; x < dataCount; x++) {

                    threadLock.lock();

                    double compare = B[x].getField();

                    threadLock.unlock();

                    if (compare == delItem) {

                        threadLock.lock();

                        B[x].decreaseFieldCount();
                        V[i].decreaseFieldCount();

                        if (B[x].getFieldCount() == 0) {
                            B[x].setCountField(-1);
                            B[x].setField(-1);
                        }

                        changed = true;

                        threadLock.unlock();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

/* */

    thread G6(threadRemove, 0, 5, dataCount, B, V, ref(sortedCount));
    thread G7(threadRemove, 5, 10, dataCount, B, V, ref(sortedCount));
    thread G8(threadRemove, 10, 15, dataCount, B, V, ref(sortedCount));
    thread G9(threadRemove, 15, 20, dataCount, B, V, ref(sortedCount));
    thread G10(threadRemove, 20, 25, dataCount, B, V, ref(sortedCount));

    G6.join();
    G7.join();
    G8.join();
    G9.join();
    G10.join();
}
```

Comment: basically, if something interrupts the control flow, for example an exception (I don't know what `DataB` does), locked locks will be left locked in the current thread forever. Use `std::lock_guard` instead.

Comment: @Incomputable I'll include DataB code now. I'll look into `lock_guard`

Comment: It would be nice to have an executable example with a small, typical data set so we can run the code on our machines (to help in finding non-obvious issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Contention

There is only **one** `std::mutex`, and **every** thread is permanently in contention for that **same** lock **for every small partial operation**. Thus, all the threads are permanently in contention over that lock, and at most one thread at a time is actually doing any work. A single threaded implementation should be faster - it has to do the same work, but doesn't have to fight over lock control.

So, how can this be fixed?

#### 1) Separate independent data per thread

In the usage example, elements of `V` are split between threads so that no two threads are accessing the same elements. So, accesses to elements of `V` don't need a lock - if this convention is followed strictly.

*If this is possible, locks aren't needed for those parts!*

#### 2) Finer granularity locks

Right now, taking the lock stops every thread from doing any work at all. Even with the improvement of option 1, only one thread at a time can access elements from `B`. This can be improved by introducing locks at a finer granularity:

- simple: one lock per array element (so one for each `DataB` object)
- more advanced: one lock for a subset of each array (e.g. one lock for every 10 array elements)

Doing so allows other threads to perform work on all unrelated elements.

#### 3) Read/Write exclusivity

What's the difference between reading and writing `B{0]`? Reading can be done concurrently, writing can't. There is a lock that helps for this special case: `std::shared_mutex` allow multiple threads to read the related object(s), but only allows one thread to write to it (while no one else can access it). The catch? It's only available since C++17. Before that, there might be other libraries providing that functionality, though (e.g. boost), or you make do with a normal `std::mutex`.

#### Small problem

In the current version, every changes to an element of `B` is done in one transaction - no thread can see any partial state. If this property is required, this can be implemented with some special considerations. How do you change a `BData` object in one transaction?

- Create a copy, change the copy, take the lock, overwrite the original with the copy, release lock (aka RCU = Read Copy Update, requires an external lock)
- Lock the object, perform changes, unlock the object (this requires giving access to an internal lock)

## Implementation

- Headers are missing, At least `<string>`, `<mutex>` and `<thread>` need to be included.
- `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice and should be avoided.
- Some member functions of `DataB` and some variables could be marked `const` (e.g. `DataB::getFieldCount()`, `DataB::getField()`, `compare`, `count`, every function parameter). Doing so might help reasoning about code and enables the compiler to verify said reasoning and might enable it to generate better machine code.
- Inconsistent naming: `DataB::getFieldCount` and `DataB::setCountField`.
- `DataB` doesn't encapsulate any behavior, it just provides some getters and setters. Maybe make it a POD struct instead?
- Prefer list initialization in the constructor(s).
- The `void` in `function_name(void)` isn't needed in C++.

## Fixed contention code

> For this, I made one internal mutex per `DataB` object and chose the second option for transactions. Also, I changed `DataB` to a POD struct to easily provide access to all internals (having getters and setters acquire locks on their own doesn't fit well with having a lock for a transaction).

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <shared_mutex>

struct DataB {
    mutable std::shared_mutex mut{}; // mutable so sonst DataB object can still be locked
    std::string name;
    double field;
    int fieldCount;

    DataB() { }
    DataB(const double sF, const int sC, const std::string& n) : name{n}, field{sF}, fieldCount{sC} {}
};

void threadRemove(const int dataStart, const int dataEnd, const int dataCount, const DataB B[], const DataB V[], const int &sortedCount) {
    bool changed = true;

    while (changed || sortedCount != dataCount) {
        changed = false;

        for (auto i = dataStart; i < dataEnd; i++) {
            if (V[i].fieldCount > 0) {
                for (auto x = 0; x < dataCount; x++) {
                    double compare;
                    {
                        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> read_lock{ B[x].mut }; // shared_lock = read only access
                        compare = B[x].field;
                    } // read_lock goes out of scope and gets released
                    if (compare == V[i].field) {
                        std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> write_lock{ B[x].mut }; // unique_lock = write access
                        --B[x].fieldCount;
                        --V[i].fieldCount;

                        if (B[x].fieldCount == 0) {
                            B[x].fieldCount = -1;
                            B[x].field = -1;
                        }

                        changed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Note

This could maybe be enhanced by strategic use of atomics. However, that would require more knowledge about the members and usages of `DataB` than I could gather/guess from the code given.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will definitely use this information in the future. Sadly I can't up-vote your comment since I do not have required reputation.

Comment: I'll also edit my question to add examples of how it should work.